# ViewPager on Android 4.3 missing content

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I have a `ListView` each item of which is `ViewPager` with some content (mostly images). Everything works fine bot not on Android 4.3 and above `ViewPager`'s content is missing and ViewPager not scrollable. I don't know which part of source code to provide here - ask me and I'll try to provide you maximum info.

EDIT: Found out that ViewPager in my case has zero dimensions. But only on Android 4.3+.

Here is part of my layout:

```
<...AdaptableHeightImageView
    android:id="@android:id/icon"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/slide"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

<...UninterceptableViewPager
    android:id="@+id/list_item_showcase_images"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@android:id/icon"
    android:overScrollMode="never" />
```

When I set `ViewPager`'s width and height 100dp for example it becomes visible.
The `UninterceptableViewPager` is `ViewPager` subclass with locked X-axes. The `AdaptableHeightImageView` is `ImageView` subclass which fits the setted width but stretches it's height to save aspect ratio. The goal is to have `ViewPager` with the same dimensions that `ImageView` has.

If I write something like this:

```
    <...UninterceptableViewPager
    android:id="@+id/list_item_showcase_images"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@android:id/icon"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/icon"
    android:layout_alignRight="@android:id/icon"
    android:layout_alignTop="@android:id/icon"
    android:overScrollMode="never" />
```

Then once my `Views` inside `ViewPager` or parent `ListView` are recycled they never appear again. Also in this case any `ViewPager` content which wasn't shown when data array is set will never be shown. But `ViewPager` will have dimensions and I even able to scroll it. Seems like Google changed something in Android 4.3.

In conclusion: everything works fine only if I set concrete width and height

Comment: If it has 0x0 dimension, the XML would be a good starting point I guess.

Comment: I've edited my question. Why it works on previous versions is incomprehensible for me.

Comment: And actually only the height is zero.

Comment: for testing purposes, instead of your custom classes use base ones and see if the problem still occurs

Comment: @pskink I've already tryed and the problem not gone.

Comment: ok so replace ViewPager with a class extending View and override onMeasure and see what happens

Comment: actually there is already such a class - AdaptableHeightImageView which stretches itself correctly.