# onMeasure second param is zero on Android 4.3+

Tags: android, android-layout, view

Don't anybody know what have been changed in view measuring? I'm getting zero second param in `onMeasure` on any device with android version 4.3 and above while on older versions it works fine.

Comment: what is your layout_height?

Comment: it's wrap_content. But as I mentioned it works on lder versions of Android. If I set for example 100dp then ViewPager becomes visible, but it's subviews are higher. Something changed in 4.3 version but I can't find out what exactly.

Comment: this question is related to another my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20093858/viewpager-on-android-4-3-missing-content#comment29939209_20093858 you can find more info there.